# How to set DI-defined Class Base Controller variables based off headers in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

For ASP.NET Core 6 Web API (not MVC - it's done in MVC already), I'm looking to use something like [custom middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/) or [filters](https://codetosolutions.com/blog/3/how-to-add-pre-and-post-processing-logic-in-asp.net-core-mvc-or-webapi) to capture a custom header that's being used to define tenancy for our application, since this is not covered by our authentication mechanism and is quite a heavy lift to do so at the moment.

The tenancy is defined by a service that's injected and used together with database and storage. The tenant service is ultimately what defines the "endpoint" being called. Tenant state for requests is set like:

```
_tenantService.SetTenant(CurrentUserService.GetLoggedUserDomain());
```

Where `ITenantService` is passed to the `ApiBaseController` to be set for all controllers. Well, in theory. In Web API, there's no way to grab those headers within the controller itself, out of the box.

In MVC, we'd do something simple like adding this helper method, which works like a charm:

```
[Controller]
public class BaseController : Controller
{    
    private readonly ITenantService _tenantService;

    public BaseController(ITenantService tenantService) => _tenantService = tenantService;

    [NonAction]
    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        _tenantService.SetTenant(CurrentUserService.GetLoggedUserDomain(null));
        ...
    }
}
```

In ASP.NET Core Web API, I've looked, and not found that option. But I've found both [custom middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/) and [custom filters](https://codetosolutions.com/blog/3/how-to-add-pre-and-post-processing-logic-in-asp.net-core-mvc-or-webapi) alternatives to do something like this.

I've been able to access the injected service (in my case - `ITenantService`), and set the `tenantService` via `.SetTenant`, but it doesn't look like that shared state is actually flowing into the controllers to be called elsewhere in the application.

So my (4) questions are:

1. Is there a better way to capture this header and `.setTenant()` from within the `BaseController`, rather than external filter or middleware files? That way, it can be ruled out as a point of failure.
2. If (1) is not possible, do I need to set the controller to have some sort of either `scoped` or `transient` DI state? Or should it be sharing with either of the below filters or middleware?
3. For custom middleware, is there a way that I can set the DI state of the controller so that it is shared or persistent, from when it is set within the middleware (example of my middleware below):

Middleware example, referenced in program.cs via `app.UseMyCustomMiddleware()`

```
public class MyCustomMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public MyCustomMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    /**
      * Middleware is constructed at app startup and therefore has application life time.
      * Scoped lifetime services used by middleware constructors aren't shared with other
      * dependency-injected types during each request. To share a scoped service between middleware and other types,
      * add these services to the InvokeAsync method's signature.
      * The InvokeAsync method can accept additional parameters that are populated by DI:
      */
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, ITenantService tenantService)
    {
        string email = httpContext.Request.Headers["email"]; // Captures e-mail just fine

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
        {
            string domain = email[(email.LastIndexOf('@') + 1)..];
            tenantService.SetTenant(domain); // Works fine, but the tenantService isn't shared back to the controller somehow.
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("No tenant for email provided [EMAIL: " + email + "]");
        }

        await _next(httpContext);
    }
}

public static class MyCustomMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyCustomMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<MyCustomMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

4. For custom filters, is there any way that I need to add it, e.g. `services.AddScoped<UserEmailFilter>();` or `services.AddTransient<UserEmailFilter>()`, or does it need an interface even? (middleware doesn't give the option of adding it as DI service, so it's not an option for that one)

Example of Custom filter, initialized via methods above in `Program.cs`

```
public class UserEmailFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
  private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
  protected readonly ICurrentUserService CurrentUserService;
  protected readonly ITenantService TenantService;
  protected TenantDto Tenant;
  
  public UserEmailFilter(
    IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, 
    ITenantService tenantService,
    ICurrentUserService currentUserService)
  {        
    this.TenantService = tenantService;
    this.CurrentUserService = currentUserService;
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
  }

  public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
  {
    // Do something before the action executes.

    string email = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["email"];
    if (email == null)
    {
      context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403; // BadRequest
      await context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync("User Email Missing");
      return;
    }

    Tenant = TenantService.SetTenant(CurrentUserService.GetLoggedUserDomain(email)); // Sets correctly, but TenantService isn't persisted back to the Controllers
    // next() calls the action method.
    var resultContext = await next();
    // resultContext.Result is set.
    // Do something after the action executes.
  }
}
```

---

Maybe I'm missing something simple with DI on our Web API (open to any questions to help think through what could be going wrong), or maybe there's another approach I can't think of. Really open to ideas, criticisms, suggestions, etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well you are very near to your solution...

The problem is your instantiating an instance on your own and not letting the DI handle it. The instance that is injected by the DI to your consumers is not the the one you instantiated here

```
//this remains(i.e. isn't shared of course) in your middleware/filter
Tenant = TenantService.SetTenant(CurrentUserService.GetLoggedUserDomain(email)); // Sets correctly, but TenantService isn't persisted back to the Controllers
```

What you want to do is register a single Instance in your DI, inject that to middleware, set the value and now when the controller consumes that service it will get the same instance the one you set the tenant value.

*Alternatively* you can create a static class with static Tenant property that you set in the middleware and check in your controller.

**EDIT:** Code samples...

```
Method I:
//registration of tenant service as single instance in Microsoft DI
services.AddSingleton<ITenantService, ImplementationClass>();

//middleware code:
 public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, ITenantService tenantService)
{
    //some checks
    tenantService.setTenant("foo from requestheaders headers");
}
//controller code that to consume the service
public MyControllerConstructor(ITenantService tenantService)
{
     this._tenantService = tenantService;
}

public ActionResult<bool> CheckTenantFromHeader([FromHeader]string tenant)
{
   return _tenantService.GetTenant() == tenant;
}
```

```
Method II:
//static class to hold
public static class TenantStore
{
    private static string _tenant;

    public static void SetTenant(string ten) => _tenant = ten;
    public static string GetTenant() => _tenant;
}

//middleware inside invoke after checks
TenantStore.SetTenant("foo");

//inside any controller
TenantStore.GetTenant();
```

This pattern may not be ideal and *assumes* that the middle ware is invoked such that to set the value and *then* consumers retrieves the value. The reason I would avoid this is that refactoring then becomes an issue if you have many dependencies on such static stores.

Comment: From my understanding, DI passes instances via constructors of the classes... maybe I'm missing something? If you have a code example, I'm happy to try anything to see.

Comment: So method 1 is exactly what I was doing already (when I looked at your answer), but the state wasn't shared with the controller. It's possible something was wrong with DI in general, for which the monolithic project I was working on was hard to troubleshoot (though... it's the same DI as MVC, which works). Either way, for the sense of SO re-usability, I'll try to get your code loading in a clean project, and if it works will approve as answer for others/myself down the road =)